# delphi: how to transform a TGUID to a PTypeInfo pointer?

Tags: delphi, interface, delphi-2010, rtti

I have a TGUID variable, and I want to "transform" it via Rtti to the PTypeInfo that describes that interface..

```
AGUID := StringToGUID('{19BB9F78-1FB1-4B0F-B691-82EE5CD7A941}');

.. transform AGUID to PTypeInfo ..

AInterface = GlobalContainer.Resolve( <PTypeInfo> expected);
```

Delphi 2010+

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function GetInterfaceTypeInfo(const GUID: TGUID): PTypeInfo;
var
  Ctx: TRttiContext;
  AType: TRttiType;
begin
  Result := nil;
  Ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
  try
    for AType in Ctx.GetTypes do
      if (AType.TypeKind = tkInterface) and IsEqualGUID(GetTypeData(AType.Handle)^.Guid, GUID) then
      begin
        Result := AType.Handle;
        Break;
      end;
  finally
    Ctx.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: It works! I will accept it if nobody posts a faster implementation ( one that does not have to iterate over all the types). Maybe it can be done?

Comment: You could, for example, keep your own (smaller) list of type infos and register your interface type infos manually in the list.